# Why mktime returns wrong result?

Tags: php, datetime, date, timestamp

Today is 24 gen 2012 for Europe. I'm using `mktime` to get a **DateTime** object about today, **midnight time**. Why it says *23 o'clock of 23 gen*, instead of *00:00 of 24 gen*?

```
var_dump(new DateTime('@' . mktime(0, 0, 0)));
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)[5]
  public 'date' => string '2012-01-23 23:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

Comment: mktime uses the local time zone when determining the time to use - you're probably in a location that is 1 hour off of UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mktime](https://www.php.net/mktime) uses the local time zone information when deciding what the returned time should be and returns a value that is aligned to UTC. If you want to override this, then you need to pass in an explicit `is_dst = 0` parameter

You then use this UTC time when constructing the DateTime object (this is what the `@` does), which means that the hour offset is replicated into the DateTime object.

Because `mktime` uses the local timezone information, you should use the alternative `gmmktime` if you want to obtain midnight UTC using -

```
$date = DateTime('@' . gmmktime(0, 0, 0));
```

If you want midnight server time, and then to convert the output to a user's timezone e.g. 'Europe/Paris' you would do the following:

```
$date = DateTime('@' . mktime(0, 0, 0));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
print $date->format(DateTime::RFC850) . "\n";
```

You can convert it to your server's local time using:

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful post. So, despite server settings or location, do you know how can i generate today midnight DateTime object?

Comment: midnight where, exactly? on the server, UTC, user-local time?

Comment: Perfect, midnight UTC is all that i need! Thanks!